# Video quality drops a lot when rendered

Tags: rendering

When i view it in the viewport and render, it looks perfect:

[image]

But when I see the output it looks horrible

[image]

I use eevee and mp4 encoding.

Here are my settings:

[image]

[image]

I don't know what I have done wrong. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: That's the mpeg compression. You can try reducing the keyframe interval and increasing quality (I don't know if there is a higher setting than "High Quality").

Anyway, it's better to render out a png image sequence and then use a video editor that handles compression in a better way (like adobe media encoder, for exemple) to render out the animation in video format. It's also safer, since you can resume the rendering from the latest frame rendered in case your computer crashes or is shutdown for some reason.

Comment: In video editting software there is also a "bitrate" setting when compressing video. The higher the bitrate, the better the quality (and the larger the resulting video file). I don't know if the bitrate is directly accessible in blender or if you're stuck with the "low quality" / "high quality" presets.